# Bulk insert with a different schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from a csv file with the following data.

```
Station code;DateBegin;DateEnd 
01;20100214;20100214 
02;20100214;20100214 
03;20100214;20100214
```

I am trying bulk insert as

```
BULK INSERT dbo.#tmp_station_details   
    FROM 'C:\station.csv'   
    WITH (   
         FIELDTERMINATOR ='';'',   
         FIRSTROW = 2, 
         ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''  
        )
```

But the table tmp_station_details has one extra column as Priority.
Its schema is like

```
[Station code] [Priority] [DateBegin] [DateEnd]
```

Now is this possible to bulk insert without altering the schema of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' to your "with" block.  Refer to [BOL: using a format file to skip a table column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx) for an example.

Comment: But the bpt utility is to be executed from the command prompt. Isn't there a way to do this by the query.